# Dynamically accessing a "Friend" model with two foreign-keys to "Profile"

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I've created a `Friend` model that consists of two `Profile` model instances. The reason for a separate model in the first place is due to the `Friend` model having special attributes related to the "friend" relationship.

In this `Friend` model, I am also tracking the `requester` & `accepter` of the relationship as it is significant to my site--this requires that I have a separate field for each of these, and they are FKs to the `Profile` model. Here are the two models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True, blank=True)  
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=profile_photo_upload_loc,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Friend(models.Model):
    requester = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='is_requester')
    accepter = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='is_accepter')
    requester_asks = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    accepter_asks = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
```

With this structure, in instances that I want to retrieve *all* of the `Friend` instances that a single `Profile` is a participant in, I need to make two queries: one for those in which he's the `requester` and another for those in which the profile is an `accepter`. The combination of these two querysets gives me the total list of all `Friend` relationships a `Profile` belongs to--I need this total list when making things like a message inbox.

Attempting to create a message ListView, I have made a view like this:

```
class MessageListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'chat/listview.html'
    context_object_name = 'friend_list'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user__username=self.request.user)
        as_requester_list = Friend.objects.filter(requester=profile)
        as_accepter_list = Friend.objects.filter(accepter=profile)
        return list(chain(as_accepter_list, as_requester_list))
```

The problem with this, is that while it allows for me to reach into `Friend` object attributes in the templates, I can't seem to find a convenient way to retrieve necessary `Profile` attributes that belong to *the other* participant of a friend relationship.

So in a template, I might have something like this:

```
{% for friend in friend_list %}

    {{friend.requester_asks}} <br />  

{% endfor %}
```

I'm able to access properties of the `Friend` model, but how do I access the *other* friend's (`Profile` object) attributes such as `profile_picture`?
The fact that a single user can be either `requester` or `accepter` complicates the ability to access the `Profile` model attributes.

Thanks in advance.

edit: I realize this might require a drastic change to the model relationships. I'm open to any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take advantage of the fact that you're evaluating the querysets in the view already to annotate them with an attribute that points to the FK that is not the original user.

```
for friend in as_requester_list:
    friend.other_friend = friend.accepter
for friend in as_accepter_list:
    friend.other_friend = friend.requester
```

Now you can iterate through friend_list in the template, and access

```
{{ friend.other_friend.profile_picture }}
```

and so on.

Comment: Can you suggest what to look up to read more into this(the annotation and how it's passed into the template)? I wasn't aware this was possible and I'm not even sure if this is python or django specific.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. This just adds another attribute to each instance in the lists.